# LXDE right click for software

Tags: raspberry-pi, lxde

How can I add things the the right click menu when opening files I want to add Python to the list and make it the default but it does not even appear on the list. If posable can it please be a terminal solution. I am using raspbian with the ui mods (it had the same problem with out ui mods).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PCManFM as your file manager, you can add apps to the right-click options for a file type by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.[1](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/understanding-file-associations-in-lxde-and-pcmanfm/)

> mimeapps.list allows you to:
>
> - add even more “right-click” options to PCManFM right click menu
> - set the default program for a mimetype (exactly like in defaults.list)

You can either add an application under the `[Default Applications]` section, which will make it appear for all file types, or you can associate the application with a specific file type under the `[Added Associations]` section of `mimeapps.list`.

### Look at your mimeapps.list

Run `less ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and you will notice that each mime type under `[Added Associations]` appears as `mime/type=desktop-id.desktop;` in `mimeapps.list`.[2](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/0.9.5/ar01s07.html)

### Find the mime/type you wish to associate a new app with

To find the mime and type you need to use for the particular file you wish to associate the app with, take a look at `/usr/share/mime/globs2`.[3](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html)

For example, say you want to create a new association for python files whose name end with `.py`.
`grep python /usr/share/mime/globs2` gives the output:

```
50:text/x-python:*.py
50:text/x-python:*.wsgi
50:application/x-python-bytecode:*.pyc
50:application/x-python-bytecode:*.pyo
```

You can see that `*.py` files use the mime/type of `text/x-python` so that is what you would add to your `mimeapps.list` file when associating it with an applications `.desktop` file.

### Finding the .desktop file for the app you are associating

If you are unsure of the name of the `.desktop` file that represents the app you wish to associate, you should be able to find them in your `/usr/share/applications/` directory. This is likely the first directory you will want to check. Alternatively, you may user specific `.desktop` files within the `~/.local/share/applications/` for your user.

### Edit your mimeapps.list

If you want to associate `*.py` file with the gedit text editor, you would add the following line under the `[Added Associations]` section of `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

`text/x-python=gedit.desktop;`

If gedit did not previously appear under the "Open With..." options for `*.py` files, it should now appear upon saving the update to your `mimeapps.list` configuration. These changes seem to take affect immediately.

You can now associate any applications in your `/usr/share/applications/` directory with any mime/type in your `/usr/share/mime/globs2` list.